# print column name when specific row of a column contains string in R

Tags: r, count, r-colnames

I have the following dataset

```
A    B    C    D
1!   0!   1!   0!
0!   .    1!   1!
```

I need to print the column name to each match as follows

```
matches_1     matches_0
A,C           B,D
C,D           A
```

I'm using:

```
df$matches_1 <- colSums(apply(df, 1, stringr::str_count, "1!"))
```

to count occurences of 1! in each row, but i'm not sure how to print the column name instead of the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `==` instead of `stringr`, then extracting the matching `colnames`, finally `paste` the result to get the desired output.

```
srch <- c("1!", "0!")

data.frame(
  sapply(srch, \(n) 
    apply(df == n, 1, \(x) paste(colnames(df)[x], collapse=","))), check.names=F)
   1!  0!
1 A,C B,D
2 C,D   A
```

Comment: This works nicely! Somehow, when the table contains NA instead of dots, it spits the NA values. But this code can be generalized if you substitute NA with dots

Comment: Yea, that's part of the documented behavior *Missing values (‘NA’) and ‘NaN’ values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in ‘NA’.* You can replace NAs afterwards or, like in your example, before, as you mentioned.

Comment: ... or you can use `na.omit`, e.g. `data.frame(sapply(srch, \(n) apply(df == n, 1, \(x) paste(na.omit(colnames(df)[x]), collapse=","))), check.names=F)`

Answer (score 0):

We can write a customized function:

```
my_matches <- function(df, match){
  tmp <- data.frame(which(df == match, arr.ind = TRUE))
  tmp <- split(tmp, tmp$row)
  tmp <- sapply(1:length(tmp), \(x) paste0(names(df)[tmp[[x]][,2]], collapse = ","))
  return(tmp)
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(matches_1 = my_matches(., "1!"),
         matches_0 = my_matches(., "0!"))
```

which produces:

```
   A  B  C  D matches_1 matches_0
1 1! 0! 1! 0!       A,C       B,D
2 0!  . 1! 1!       C,D         A
```

Comment: This does work for the example, but there are some caveats: if there is a value that you are trying to match that is not available on one row, all the code errors out! Also, if in the example I gave, I only have 1! on first row/column, the code is printing wrongly. Not sure why tho.